# Pear Quickform2 File Upload handling

Tags: file-upload, quickform

I'm trying to build a proper file upload handling via Pear quickform 2. 
My serverside approach would be:

```
$submitValues = $editForm->getValue();
$filename = submitValues['uploaded_image']['name'];

$move_file = move_uploaded_file(.....)
```

Is there still a function like in quickform1: isUploadedFile() to make sure its an uploaded file?
unfortunately searching the documentary didn't give me the hints I needed.

Any advice regarding this issue is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function directly :

```
is_uploaded_file($submitValues['uploaded_image']['tmp_name']);
```

See http://php.net/is_uploaded_file